# File is blank after using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, streamwriter, isolatedstoragefile

I am trying to write some data to an existing file that is within my project(local file to the project). I used the following code

```
        Uri path = new Uri(@"Notes.txt", UriKind.Relative);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            using (StreamWriter writefile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path.ToString(), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write,myIsolatedStorage)))
            {
                writefile.WriteLine("hi");
                writefile.Flush();
                writefile.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

There is no exception/error while executing the program.However the file is blank and does not contain any data.

I have set the build action of the file as 'resource' and content as 'copy if newer'.
Just to check, i removed the file and tested, it still does not give any exception, though I am trying to open in Append Mode.

**Edit:** I was opening the file in my development environment to check. However I later used the ISETool.exe to check for the file. But the file is not created at all !! Here is the updated code I used:

```
 Uri path = new Uri(@"Notes.txt", UriKind.Relative);
 using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path.ToString(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage))
 using (var writefile = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writefile.WriteLine("hi");
        }
```

Comment: how are you checking to see if the file has any data?

Comment: I opened the file manually to check for any data

Comment: manually from where? Did you download it from the app using the IsolatedStorageTool?

Comment: No. I created the file- Notes.txt in the same folder where my mainpage.xaml is present. I am trying to write to that file.

Comment: my point is: How are you looking at the file to see if it's changed? For you to see if it's changed, you will have to have downloaded it from the emulator/device. It's not going to change in your development environment.

Comment: Oh! I see. I opened the file in the project path - Visual Studio 2010\Projects\<project name>. I am testing it via emulator. How can I verify it otherwise.

Comment: I'd use the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to access the isolated storage, then download the file from the emulator and check your file.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

Based on your comments above, I think your problem is actually that you have misunderstood how Isolated Storage works; it stores files *on your phone* or inside the *emulator image*, neither of which are your development machine's native file system.

If you need to access the file from your development machine, you'll need a utility like [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) (c/o [Alastair Pitts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120243/alastair-pitts), above) or [the SDK's isetool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) if you don't mind the command line interface.

**Original post**

Two things to jump out at me:

1. You're not disposing your `IsolatedStorageFileStream`
2. You should obtain your instance of `IsolatedStorageFileStream` from the `IsolatedStorageFile`
3. You don't need to call `Dispose` on `writefile` (that's what `using` does)

Try this:

```
using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var stream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(path.ToString(), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writefile = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writefile.WriteLine("hi");
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code. same result :( does it got to do anything with the Build action or content? or the path of the file? I have the file in the same folder where mainpage.xaml is present.

Comment: Please check my edited question. A folder "IsolatedStore" was downloaded when i tried to download all files to the local drive. The folder didn't contain any file "Notes.txt" at all.

Comment: If it fails to write to the file system, it would throw an exception. Have you tried debugging and checking that the code actually executes? It it does, try opening the file afterwards (in a separate using block) to see if the data is readable.

Comment: I gave the filename directly instead of giving it as an URI..It worked ! Thanks:)